# Using ng-src with ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to show some image from dynamic `ng-src` using `ng-bind-html`. Here is the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/EmHSUEbVTdUT7cqJ0nX6?p=preview

But the image isn't rendered. How to get it worked?

The purpose is, that I want to load some html-elements from DB and show them using `ng-bind-html`. Sometimes those elements are images (contain `ng-src` attribute) and sometimes they are `<i></i>` elements (which get rendered correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$interpolate`:

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/ikSeAKo15HMyQZJ88UDU?p=preview)

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $sce, $interpolate) {
    $scope.image = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Lorem_Ipsum_Helvetica.png";

    $scope.myText = $interpolate("My name is: <h1>John Doe</h1>" + "<img src='{{image | trustUrl}}'/>")($scope);
    $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.myText);
});
```

From [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate):

> `$interpolate` Compiles a string with markup into an interpolation function. This service is used by the HTML $compile service for data binding